# Traefik as an ingress controller always returns 404

Tags: traefik

I've a Kubernetes cluster which currently works with haproxy ingress controller (and is working fine). I'm trying traefik as an ingress controller, but it always return 404 even for requests which do not return 404 when using the haproxy ingress controller.

```
traefik config -- 
[entryPoints]
[entryPoints.http]
    address = "S.S.S.S:80"
[entryPoints.https]
    address = "S.S.S.S:443"
```

The (simplified) Ingress object looks like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
    rules:
    - host: apifrontend.example.com
    http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: apifrontend-web
            servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

Command line switch --

```
traefik_linux-amd64-1.5.4 -c /etc/traefik.conf --kubernetes --kubernetes.watch --kubernetes.endpoint=https://Y.Y.Y.Y:8897 --kubernetes.token='XXXXXXXX' --accesslog --loglevel=DEBUG
INFO[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Using TOML configuration file /etc/traefik.conf
INFO[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Traefik version v1.5.3 built on 2018-02-27_02:47:04PM
INFO[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30]
Stats collection is disabled.
Help us improve Traefik by turning this feature on :)
More details on: https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#collected-data

DEBU[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Global configuration loaded {"LifeCycle":{"RequestAcceptGraceTimeout":"0s","GraceTimeOut":"10s"},"Grac
eTimeOut":"0s","Debug":false,"CheckNewVersion":true,"SendAnonymousUsage":false,"AccessLogsFile":"","AccessLog":{"format":"common"},"Tr
aefikLogsFile":"","TraefikLog":null,"LogLevel":"DEBUG","EntryPoints":{"http":{"Network":"","Address":"S.S.S.S:80","TLS":null,"R
edirect":null,"Auth":null,"WhitelistSourceRange":null,"Compress":false,"ProxyProtocol":null,"ForwardedHeaders":{"Insecure":true,"Trust
edIPs":null}},"https":{"Network":"","Address":"S.S.S.S:443","TLS":null,"Redirect":null,"Auth":null,"WhitelistSourceRange":null,
"Compress":false,"ProxyProtocol":null,"ForwardedHeaders":{"Insecure":true,"TrustedIPs":null}}},"Cluster":null,"Constraints":[],"ACME":
null,"DefaultEntryPoints":["http"],"ProvidersThrottleDuration":"2s","MaxIdleConnsPerHost":200,"IdleTimeout":"0s","InsecureSkipVerify":
false,"RootCAs":null,"Retry":null,"HealthCheck":{"Interval":"30s"},"RespondingTimeouts":null,"ForwardingTimeouts":null,"Web":null,"Doc
ker":null,"File":null,"Marathon":null,"Consul":null,"ConsulCatalog":null,"Etcd":null,"Zookeeper":null,"Boltdb":null,"Kubernetes":{"Wat
ch":true,"Filename":"","Constraints":[],"Trace":false,"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate":false,"Endpoint":"https://Y.Y.Y.Y:8897","Token":"XXXXXXXXXXX","CertAuthFilePath":"","DisablePassHostHeaders":false,"EnablePassT
LSCert":false,"Namespaces":null,"LabelSelector":""},"Mesos":null,"Eureka":null,"ECS":null,"Rancher":null,"DynamoDB":null,"ServiceFabri
c":null,"Rest":null,"API":null,"Metrics":null,"Ping":null}
INFO[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Preparing server http &{Network: Address:S.S.S.S:80 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> Whiteli
stSourceRange:[] Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc420671c20} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0
s
INFO[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Preparing server https &{Network: Address:S.S.S.S:443 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> White
listSourceRange:[] Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc420671c40} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3
m0s
INFO[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Starting server on S.S.S.S:80
INFO[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Starting server on S.S.S.S:443
INFO[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Starting provider *kubernetes.Provider {"Watch":true,"Filename":"","Constraints":[],"Trace":false,"Deb
ugLogGeneratedTemplate":false,"Endpoint":"https://Y.Y.Y.Y:8897","Token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX","CertAuthFilePath":"","DisablePassHostHeaders":false,"EnablePassTLSCert":false,"Namespaces":null,"LabelSelector":""}
INFO[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Creating cluster-external Provider client with endpoint https://Y.Y.Y.Y:8897
DEBU[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Using label selector: ''
DEBU[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Received Kubernetes event kind *v1.Endpoints
DEBU[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Configuration received from provider kubernetes: {}
INFO[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Server configuration reloaded on S.S.S.S:80
INFO[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Server configuration reloaded on S.S.S.S:443
DEBU[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Received Kubernetes event kind *v1.Endpoints
DEBU[2018-03-20T11:48:49+05:30] Skipping Kubernetes event kind *v1.Endpoints
DEBU[2018-03-20T11:48:50+05:30] Received Kubernetes event kind *v1.Endpoints
DEBU[2018-03-20T11:48:50+05:30] Skipping Kubernetes event kind *v1.Endpoints
DEBU[2018-03-20T11:48:51+05:30] Received Kubernetes event kind *v1.Secret
DEBU[2018-03-20T11:48:51+05:30] Skipping Kubernetes event kind *v1.Secret
DEBU[2018-03-20T11:48:51+05:30] Received Kubernetes event kind *v1.Secret
DEBU[2018-03-20T11:48:51+05:30] Skipping Kubernetes event kind *v1.Secret
DEBU[2018-03-20T11:48:51+05:30] Received Kubernetes event kind *v1.Secret
DEBU[2018-03-20T11:48:51+05:30] Skipping Kubernetes event kind *v1.Secret
...
...
...
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: The logs seem to indicate that neither an Ingress nor a Service object was found. However, they are both needed to build proper frontend and backend configurations.

If they _are_ available in your cluster, could you please share the corresponding manifests?

Comment: But haproxy is working fine in the same setup. It sees all those ingresses which traefik cannot. Apparently, traefik has a bug which the team refuse to admit.

https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3056

Comment: I don't know how the HAProxy Ingress controller works exactly and whether its behavior might differ somehow. It could still be a configuration mismatch problem. The team does not "refuse to admit" a bug: the issue tracker is supposed to be for _known_ bugs (and feature request). I realize this comes at some level of inconvenience, but it's necessary for ticket hygiene and effective supporting. Regardless of whether this is a configuration problem or bug, we'd need to see your Kubernetes object / manifest definitions.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/P6hTh6jnNG/

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: I extended your question by relevant portions from your Ingress object and added an answer as I think I know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ingress object contains an Ingress class annotation specifying Nginx:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

This causes Traefik to ignore such objects. What you need to do instead is replace `nginx` by `traefik` or remove the annotation entirely. See also the [Traefik documentation in this regard](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.5/user-guide/kubernetes/#between-trfik-and-other-ingress-controller-implementations).

Comment: Yes, I did change one of them to traefik with no affect.

Comment: Could you update your initial question with the updated debug logs? And just to be safe, please update the manifests as well.